# Importing an .obj file and nothing is showing

Tags: obj

A little bit of context, i've ripped some models from the game Yugioh duelist of the roses and was a able to open them in 3ds max to edit some of the stuff. after doing that I save the kind of deformed models as .obj and try to open them in blender but every time I try nothing shows up. its showing I have something in the outliner but no object appears! If anybody can point me in the right direction for how to fix this id greatly appreciate it! [image]

Comment: Might be too small/large to see? Try editing the scale in the properties panel.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the scale doesn't change anything. I can change the scale up to a 1000 on x,y or z and still nothing shows. Thank you for the recommendation though !

Comment: Open the Python console and type `D.meshes[0].vertices[0].co`. What does it print?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117182/my-object-isnt-showing-up-when-i-import-it?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly/36303#36303

Comment: putting D.meshes[0].vertices[0].co into the console got me a Vector((1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) output.