# Imported object not showing up

Tags: modeling, objects, import, obj

I'm new to Blender (so hopefully this isn't too obvious) and I've recently been trying to import obj files but when I do, nothing shows up. I'm sure the object I'm importing is .obj, and when I import it, it shows up on the scene collection menu but I just can't see it...

I don't know if there's something that I'm missing here or something, but I just can't seem to see the object that I imported.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Clicked "File"
2. Clicked "Import"
3. Clicked "Wavefront (.obj)"
4. Selected the file and imported

From there on I could see nothing. Help? (I'm using Blender 2.91.2 on Windows 10)

Comment: Can you try selecting the object from the outliner and pressing the period [.] key on your numpad?  This should center the camera on the selected object's geometry.  If this has no effect it likely means the object has no geometry, which could either be a problem with the .obj file or the importer.  In the latter case you could report it as a bug.

Comment: Please use the search box at the top to find information in this site. This is a common question that has been answered many times: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117182/my-object-isnt-showing-up-when-i-import-it?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207191/when-i-import-obj-file-it-does-not-show?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89710/why-when-importing-an-obj-file-nothing-appears-even-when-zooming?noredirect=1&lq=1